# Как написать разные правила в .htaccess для разных адресов URL?

Tags: url, .htaccess

Какое правило написать для того, чтобы адрес `/blog/index` и `/news/index` открывался по адресу `/blog` и `/news` соответсвенно.
Остальные адреса оставить без изменений.

Сейчас уже используется правило

```
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Как написать правило и объединить с вышеуказанным?